# How to change layout of edit order page in Woocommerce? move

Tags: php, woocommerce

Sometime customer orders too many produces , and we cannot see shipping way first .
We just want to move order_shipping_line_item up to order_line_ items simply.
Anyone knows how to change it ? We hope the final layout is in the right side on pic.
Thanks for your help
[We hope the final layout is in the right side on pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCtNG.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question lacks information to get any help from [so] users. Please take the [tour], and read through the [help], learn  [ask] a good question? to maximize your chance to get answer to your questions. If you run into a specific problem and if you're stuck, send a description of the problem, including a [mcve] and people will be very glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit and add a filter in `woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-order-items.php` at Line 57 before the `<tbody>`. Please note that editing the core files is not recommended.

Add the below line at line 57 `<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_items_before_items', $line_items_shipping, $order ); ?>` ( This line you have to add each time you update the woocommerce plugin. )

After that add the following code in the `functions.php` file of your active theme.

```
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_items_before_items', 'wc_admin_order_items_before_items', 10, 2);

function wc_admin_order_items_before_items($line_items_shipping, $order) {
        ?>
    <tbody id="order_shipping_line_items">
    <?php
        $shipping_methods = WC()->shipping() ? WC()->shipping()->load_shipping_methods() : array();
        foreach ($line_items_shipping as $item_id => $item) {
            include WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-order-shipping.php';
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
    <?php
}
```